# Converting Pk[Long] to Option[Long] in a Form

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, anorm

I have been having trouble understanding what the issue is here since the Scala Anorm Pk became deprecated.

I switched my model to the following:

```scala
case class Item(id: Option[Long] = NotAssigned,
            title: String,
            descr: String,
            created: Option[Date],
            private val imgs: List[Img],
            private val tags: List[Tag])
```

From `id: Pk[Long]`

I changed my form to:

```scala
val itemForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> ignored(23L),
      "title" -> nonEmptyText,
      "descr" -> nonEmptyText,
      "created" -> optional(ignored(new Date)),
      "imgs" -> Forms.list(itemImgs),
      "tags" -> Forms.list(itemTags)
    )(Item.apply)(Item.unapply)
)
```

From `"id" -> ignored(NotAssigned:Pk[Long])`

But, I get this error.

`type mismatch; found : (Option[Long], String, String, scala.math.BigDecimal, Option[java.util.Date], List[models.Img], List[models.Tag]) => models.Item required: (Long, String, String, Option[java.util.Date], List[models.Img], List[models.Tag]) => ?
)(Item.apply)(Item.unapply)`

Why is an `Option[Long]` not required on the Item model?

I don't know what `23L` is, but that's what was in the Play Documentation. The value of id in the database is coming from a sequence.

If I change it to:

```
"id" -> ignored(NotAssigned:Option[Long]),
```

Which makes the most sense to me... I get this error:

`type mismatch; found : anorm.NotAssigned.type required: Option[Long]
"id" -> ignored(NotAssigned:Option[Long]),`

Which makes less sense than before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, it's not Anorm that's deprecated, but the `Pk` type within Anorm.

Your problem here is that you're trying to assign `NotAssigned` to an `Option[Long]`, which is incompatible. You should change all of the `NotAssigned`s to `None`.

So your class would look like this:

```
case class Item(
    id: Option[Long] = None,
    title: String,
    descr: String,
    price: BigDecimal,
    created: Option[Date],
    private val imgs: List[Img],
    private val tags: List[Tag]
)
```

And the `Form` mapping:

```
"id" -> ignored[Option[Long]](None)
```

Comment: This worked. Finally, thank you. I also have a `BigDecimal` up there that shouldn't be there, but the problem existed before that. I just wanted to mention it in case anyone caught it. :)

Comment: `"id" -> Option.empty[Long]` would be more compatible with next Anorm revisions.